# Getting MAX() of each row with an ARRAYFORMULA()

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Using an array formula I want to find the max value of each row of a range and get the resulting range to work with it further.

The problem occurs as soon as I add the `MAX()` statement since it does seem to behave strangely within an array formula. Even if you ad commands which will give you multiple values within the `MAX()` statement it does always only return one single value.

E.g. this will give you the ranges which I want to get the max of:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(ROW(E1:E11); COLUMN() + 1; 4) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(E1:E11); COLUMN() + 4; 4))
```

The result looks like the following:

```
F1:I1
F2:I2
F3:I3
F4:I4
F5:I5
F6:I6
F7:I7
F8:I8
F9:I9
F10:I10
F11:I11
```

If I now add `INDIRECT()` to make those to actual ranges and add `MAX()` it should return the max of each of those ranges since the array formula should go through the `ROW(E1:11)` as it did bevor. However, the result of this new formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(E1:E11); COLUMN() + 1; 4) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(E1:E11); COLUMN() + 4; 4))))
```

rather is one single value, the maximum of the first range.

I have even tried to bypass the problem by adding an `IF()` statement for the array formula to iterate through the rows. Doing so, it did give me a result for all 11 rows, however, the result always was the same (the max of the first row).

The new formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(E1:E11) = ROW(E1:E11); MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(E1:E11); COLUMN() + 1; 4) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(E1:E11); COLUMN() + 4; 4))); ""))
```

The new result (left column are the results of the formula, trying to get the max of each row to its right):

```
10  7   10  4   1
10  10  8   1   2
10  4   5   9   4
10  10  10  2   2
10  10  10  5   10
10  10  6   9   5
10  4   5   7   3
10  6   9   4   7
10  5   5   7   3
10  9   2   3   10
10  10  3   9   10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F1:I), 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F1:F&G1:G&H1:H&I1:I), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(F1:F)-ROW(F1)+1&"),", ""))), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2")
```

[image: 0]